# Is the cube with boundary and corners a manifold with boundary?

Tags: manifolds

The definition of a n-manifold with boundary as I understand it, is that the manifold without boundary is an n-manifold, and the boundary is an (n-1)-manifold. Thus because the boundary of cube has edges and corners, which are of a lower dimension than 2, would the boundary not be a 2-manifold? This seems right, but I wanted to verify that my logic is correct.

Comment: edges and corners don't do anything topologically, so the boundary of a cube is a topological sphere.

Comment: If you are referring to a differentiable manifold, then this is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're talking about differentiable manifolds here. In that case (as has been noted in comments) the boundary of a cube is not a 2-manifold with boundary.

It's worth looking up the definition of "manifold with corners" (or trying to guess what it should be yourself). <strike>You'll see that the boundary of cube is a 2-dimensional manifold with corners.</strike>

**Edit:** Sorry, I made a mistake before: the *solid* cube is a 3-dimensional manifold with corners, but I don't believe the boundary is (though I guess it can be thought of as a piecewise-linear manifold).

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I was talking about differentiable manifolds. My class covered them very loosely in the last few days of class, and this was a book question.

Answer (score 1):

The boundary of a solid cube in 3-space seems to be the object you're talking about. Topologically, it's the same as the 2-sphere (the surface of the earth, for example). In the smooth category, it also happens to be the image of smooth map from the sphere to 3-space, but this smooth map is singular at each vertex and along each edge.